# I have configured DDNS in my Tp-link router with No-IP, how do I get to my router's settings page from my No-IP account

Tags: wireless-router, port-forwarding, dynamic-dns, ddns, noip

As I mentioned in the title, and according to what a friend of mine told me, that if I linked my router using the **DDNS** feature, I can get access to it just from my **DDNS** Provider account.
I have done that successfully, but I don't know how do I get to my router's settings page from my **No-IP** account, can someone help me please and ***thanks in advance***.

Comment: Like everyone mentioned you shouldn’t do this. But this is a function of the router, not No IP. Please [edit] your question and provide the model of your router.

Comment: If your router is capable of it, run a vpn server on your router, then use a vpn client to connect to it (using the ddns IP ad the server name).  This will mitigate the security issues and, depending on your router, may bypass the additional restrictions on WAN access [when using the vpn interface ip]

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible that there is no access from the WAN side. Allowing it could be a serious security issue. You access it from 'inside'.

I don't even allow access over wifi on mine. You have to be in the building, connected to Ethernet to access it. That keeps it safe from fly-by attacks too.
I'd check the manual to see if it's user-configurable. I'd imagine it may be locked out on domestic routers to prevent people opening themselves up top attack unwittingly.

*Late edit*: I didn't consider the OP may not be aware of the functionality of DDNS - in that all it does is link a domain name to a 'moving target' IP address. I'd only considered what you do once you've made that association.

Answer (score 1):

[Dynamic DNS (DDNS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS)
does not allow access to your router. What it does is associate a
domain-name with the public IP address of your router.
If your ISP will change your public IP in the future, you can keep
accessing your home via the name, which never changes, rather than
using the new IP address.

The No-IP account itself serves for nothing except allowing you to
use the No-IP services for creating that association. That's all it does.

If the router is set to allow login via the internet (**not recommended**),
you may use this name for accessing it.

However, the usual way this is used is to access your *computer* from
the internet. This requires
[Port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding)
the service port by the router. For example, forwarding port 80
to your computer if you set up a web-server for use by other people,
or as another example a minecraft server for your friends to play.

I suggest studying well this subject, since a mistake might open
your computer to direct attacks from the internet.